# Operatos privilege windows 10 and deployment

Tags: ussd, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-iot-core

I want to develop a windows phone 10 application using USSD/SMS API. The application doesn't need to be in the windows store.

I would like to know if:

1. the development and test of this kind of application is possible
   without being an Operator;
2. the manually deployment on 1000 devices is possible.

Thank you

Comment: no you can not do this unless Microsoft provisions you to use the apis

Answer (score 0):

Universal SMS API in windows 10 can be used to send and receive SMS. Here is the link for the sample application: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive . It requires restricted capability "cellularMessaging" (microsoft partners can request access). While verifying the changes check if the device is unlocked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx.